# How to get the HAR file of network log at runtime?

Tags: python

```
     world.responseXml = ''
            # getting elements in between
```

I am doing it like below mention code in python (using harParser) -

```
        self.write(self.driver.har, "info")
        har_parser = HarParser(json.loads(self.driver.har))
        data = har_parser.har_data
        self.write(data.keys(), "info")
```

then travesing -

```
 for page in har_parser.pages:
    for entry in page.entries:
                if url in str(entry['response']['content'].get('text', '')):
                    world.split1 = str(str(entry['response']['content'].get('text', '')).split(url)

       idx1 = world.split1.index("responseXML")
       idx2 = world.split1.index('<div class="waitMessage" >')
       res = ''
       # getting elements in between
            for idx in range(idx1 + len("responseXML") + 1, idx2):
                res = res + world.split1[idx]
                self.write(res, "info")

            idx3 = res.index('value="')
            idx4 = res.index('">')
                   for idx in range(idx3 + len('value="'), idx4):
                world.responseXml = world.responseXml + res[idx]
```

In Response i am not getting complete network log. It is loading only below mentioned -
` "log": {
"version": "1.2",
"creator": {
"name": "Selenium Wire HAR dump",
"version": "5.1.0",
"comment": "Selenium Wire version 5.1.0"
},
"entries": []
}
}

whereas it should get like this -
{
"log": {
"version": "1.2",
"creator": {
"name": "WebInspector",
"version": "537.36"
},
"pages": [
{
and so on
}]
`